# JQuery Post call return a server 500 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I can't make to work a Jquery post call in my new server. I was testing send a post call when I close a Jquery Ui dialog, which [send a sms trough Twilio interface](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages). It's working in my old server but when I installed it in my new server it doesn't work, I don't know why.

THis is the button who sent the post call:

```
    $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width:240,
        height:250,
        modal:true,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "fade",
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {

                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                $.post("tmpl/do/sms.php", { cantidad : $("#test").val() });
            }
        }
    }).css("font-size", "16px");
```

And this is the PHP which receive that call:

```
    <?php       
      require("twilio/Services/Twilio.php");
      // require POST request       
      if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") die;
      $number = ($_POST["cantidad"]);
      $AccountSid = "Axxxxx";       
      $AuthToken = "axxxxxxx";
      // Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client       
      $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
      try {     
        // make call        
    $call = $client->account->sms_messages->create(     
      'xxxxx,        // From        
      '+xxxxx',     // To       
      'yyyyy' // SMS        
        );      
      } catch (Exception $e) {      
        echo 'Error sending sms: ' . $e->getMessage();      
      }
    ?>
```

If I press the button in the dialog it send a error 500 in the console. If someone has any idea, I'll be really thankful

Comment: You're missing a " ' " $call = $client->account->sms_messages->create('xxxxx,  
If you open the url tmpl/do/sms.php do you get any errors? Have you got php to report errors?

Comment: As I can see for now, you may have a problem with `require` - wrong path, for instance, or something inside `Twilio.php`. Another possible problem - missing closing quotation mark in from field. To get more info - check out php error log file.

Comment: I fixed the missing "'" but still receiving error 500. When I have it in my old server it worked perfectly but in the new one shows this error.

Answer (score -1):

Possible solutions from the comments include:

> You're missing a " ' " $call =
>   $client->account->sms_messages->create('xxxxx, If you open the url
>   tmpl/do/sms.php do you get any errors?
>
> You may have a problem with require - wrong path, for instance, or
>   something inside Twilio.php. Another possible problem - missing
>   closing quotation mark in from field. To get more info - check out php
>   error log file.